# Prove if there is a group whose order is $p^2$,and it is non-abelian, then it is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> Suppose the non-abelian group G whose order is $p^2$ where p is a prime number, prove it is a cyclic group.

My work:

there is a $\tau\not=e$ in the group and the order of $\tau$ is either $p$ or $p^2$, if the latter, the problem can be solved. so if it exists a element whose order is $p^2$, the group G is a cyclic group. But I can't prove it. Can you prove it or give some hint so I can continue do it? Thank you!

Comment: The simplest way to see this is to use/prove the lemmas that A) a $p$-group has a non-trivial center, and B) if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. Both have been covered on our site (and at groupprops.wiki)

Comment: Your question is wrong. Group with order p^2 where p is prime always abelian.

Comment: @JohnNash I don't see how the question could be wrong. The proposed statement is vacuously true, and proving it directly would be another way of proving that non-Abelian groups of order $p^2$ do not exist. Are you sure there is no such proof?

Comment: If group is non abelian then how it is cyclic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is odd.  It is well-known that a group of order $p^2$ is abelian.  A proof would go like this:  $p$-groups have nontrivial center $\implies G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\implies G$ is abelian.

Furthermore your setup is incorrect.  A cyclic group is *always* abelian.

Comment: Well yes, but can one prove that "a non-Abelian group of order $p^2$ is cyclic" **without** using that well-known fact? If so, that would be an alternative way of proving that a group of order $p^2$ is Abelian. Are you sure there is no proof along those lines? I wouldn't know, just an amateur dilettante, don't know any group theory.